# C# Call a function from another class

Tags: c#, discord.net

I've got 2 classes one that contains the function and then one that contains the command, i'm fairly new to this and cannot figure out how to call the function.

This is the function i'm trying to call

```
private async Task<long> GetMemberId(string members)
{
   long memberID = 0;

   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(StaticObjects.bungieBasePath 
                                  + $@"/GroupV2/Name/{memberID}/1/");
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
      try
      {
         dynamic content = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ExpandoObject>().Result;
         Debug.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
      }
      catch
      {
         throw new ArgumentException("The member could not be found.");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      throw new ArgumentException("An error occurred retrieving the members information.");
   }

   return memberID;
}
```

Then this is the command

```
[Command("invite")]
[RequireContext(ContextType.Guild, ErrorMessage = "This command is specific to a particular server so you must send it from a channel within that server")]
public async Task SendInviteAsync()
{
   await Context.Channel.TriggerTypingAsync(new RequestOptions() { Timeout = 30 });

   if (!Context.IsPrivate) await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();

   if (StaticObjects.CheckUserIsAdmin(Context))
   {
      //command to call the memberid function
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to call it from whatever class 'GetMemberId' is in - which either means you have to have an instance of that class instantiated or have it be a static method.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `class` and it's an instance? Generally, you should somehow inject or create an instance of the `class` and invoke the specified method...

Comment: It's `private` - you can't call it outside of its class. Make it `internal` or `public`.

Comment: It is worth noting that this pattern is not encouraged with D.Net; all permission or condition checks should be moved into Preconditions. See [Preconditions on Discord.Net Nightly Documentation](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/commands/preconditions.html). Additionally, `RequestOptions.Timeout` does not do what you think it does. If you wish to have the bot enter typing state for as long as the task is being carried out, you should use `IMessageChannel.EnterTypingState` while having it wrapped in a `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

`GetMemberId` is a private function and can only be used within its class. You'll need to make it public and then call it from the other class like this:

```
if (StaticObjects.CheckUserIsAdmin(Context))
{
    var class = new firstClass();
    var memberId = class.GetMemberId(members);
}
```